# when show invalid feedback message break the input icon

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

This is my error:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group has-icon-left">
        <label class="form-label" for="first-name-icon">Company Name</label>
        <div class="position-relative ">
            <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Company Name"
                   id="first-name-icon" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required />
            <div class="form-control-icon">
                <i class="bi bi-person "></i>
            </div>
            <span class="invalid-feedback ">Please provide a company name.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to show invalid feedback error message for client validation, but when I show error message under the input box thats the time input icon break the shape.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it after the form group.

```
 <div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group has-icon-left">
        ...
    </div>

    <span class="invalid-feedback ">Please provide a company name.</span>

    <div>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have more input field , I want to show all input field invalid error message